# Vue 3 v-model not properly updating on in Andoid's Chrome?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component, which is essentially an input/select hybrid field, which allows users to type in the input field, and select items from the dropdown, based on their query.

It works perfectly fine on most devices I've tried, i.e. as the user types something into the input field, the list of items updates and only shows those items which contain that piece of string.

Except the Chrome browser on my Android device - as you type, the list doesn't seem to update, unless I press the "space bar". Very strange. Anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Here is the code in `<script setup>`:

```
const props = defineProps([ 'items', 'searchBy' ])
const searchTerm = ref('')

const itemsToShow = computed(() => {
    if (props.items) {
      if (searchTerm.value) {
        return props.items.filter(el => {
          if (props.searchBy) {
            return el[props.searchBy].toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.value.toUpperCase()) > -1  
          }

          return el.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm.value.toUpperCase()) > -1
        })
      } else {
        return props.items
      }
    } else {
      return []
    }
})
```

And the HTML:

```
    <input 
      type="text" 
      class="input"
      v-model="searchTerm"
      placeholder=" " 
    />
    <div class="items-list">
      <div 
        v-for="item in itemsToShow" 
        :key="item" 
        @click="() => handleAdd(item)" 
        class="item text"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </div>
      <div 
        v-if="!itemsToShow.length" 
        class="text"
      >
        No items match searched term
      </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:

I've investigated a little, and it seems the `searchTerm` ref, isn't updating properly, even though its bound using `v-model`... Still no idea why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this issue before.

It seems that on certain devices, the `v-model` waits for a `change` event, instead of an `input` one.

Apparently, it's to do with the input method editor (IME) for the specific device.

You can check a discussion about this at https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5580

The workaround is to simply bind the input field with `value` and listen for the `input` event manually, e.g.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="input"
  :value="searchTerm"
  @input="(e) => searchTerm = e.target.value"
  placeholder=" " 
/>
```